# SQL ROW TO COLUMN

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as follow
OPERATIONS

```
OPERATOR-OPERATION TYPE
Ahmet   DELETE
Ahmet   UPDATE
Ahmet   READ
Salih   DELETE
Salih   UPDATE
Salih   READ
Salih   READ
Salih   CREATE
```

What SQL will be to get following result? When simple COUNT, GROUP BY clauses used Operation types written as ROW based.

```
Name- Total- DELETE- READ- UPDATE  CREATE
Ahmet 3      1       1     1       0
Salih 5      1       2     1       1
```

Comment: It depends on your RDBMS. Could you please tag your question with this? This is known as a PIVOT operation - there are quite a few questions on SO relating to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select operator, 
       count(*) as total,
       sum(case when operation_type = 'DELETE' then 1 else 0 end) as deletes,
       sum(case when operation_type = 'UPDATE' then 1 else 0 end) as updates,
       sum(case when operation_type = 'READ' then 1 else 0 end) as reads,
       sum(case when operation_type = 'CREATE' then 1 else 0 end) as creates
from operations
group by operator
```

Comment: This may not be the best way if the OP is on a database that supports PIVOT... you're missing total and you haven't capitalised the operation type correctly...

Comment: is there a way to automatize the adding of operator type by reading from OPERATION_TYPES table.

Comment: @mmc18 Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24057529/2118383